# Why do Mapbox Place Search (forward geocoding) coordinates not match features on v11 map?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I have implemented a simple map with a geocoder search field as explained on https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder/

If you go to the above example and type "Russia" in the search bar, the map will put a marker on Moscow.

However, in the v11 map template the country label "Russia" is somewhere totally different (much further to the right in the center of the country). So if you query the rendered features on the label "Russia" on the map, you will also get the point for the country Russia.

This causes some discrepancy for users that want to set a marker on "Russia" either by

a) clicking on the map label "Russia" and receiving the correct properties for this point including type "country"

opposed to

b) search for "Russia" in the geocoder input field and fly to Moscow instead of the center of the country

This is true not only for countries, but most features on the map. They simply don't exactly match the results of the geocoder. So users would end up with two markers for the same feature depending on which way the added the marker (via the geocoder or by clicking on the map).

Is there a way to make them match? Ideally I would like to use all features of the v11 map in the geocoder search. Is it possible to use the v11 map features as the data source for the geocoder?

Comment: I believe this is because the data sources are different, the map is mostly OpenStreetMap data and the search is a combination of other sources plus Foursquare.

Comment: Yes, I believe that, too. But is there a way to use the map data for the geocoder (or built one on top of that data) instead of working with two different data sources?